# listview in android activity

Tags: android, listview

I have a table as **contents** name. In content table there are 4 field : `id,lable,des,typ`.

`content` table is used for poems data.

`id` is filled by Integer and it's **PrimaryKey**.

`lable` is label of poem.

`des` is full description of poem .

`type` is type of poem and it filled by "old" or "new".

Now , I'm going to display lables as listview when typ is equal "old" then I want to click on its each node and starts a new activity . I hope in new opened activity display des of poem .

(I can create a listview for a specific data and display them and start a new activity when I click on its node BUT I can't display des of poem in new activity)

How can I do it ?

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution, you can search for the des with the id of the lable that was clicked before you start the second activity. The des you can easily forwarded to the second activity.

```
Intent i=new Intent(context, Poem.class);
i.putExtra("des", yourDes);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Second activity (in the onCreate method):

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String des = intent.getStringExtra("des");
```

more defenseve:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
String des;

if (extras != null) 
{
    des = extras.getString("des");
}
```

Comment: thanks for your replies.I created a List of label for adapter of ListView.List<String> listData = new ArrayList<String>(); now how can i fetch LABEL and DES from sqlite and use LABEL for listView and use DES for passing to newActivity ?

Comment: you can create a custome adapter (http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92) with this you can store the id and the label, the label you display in your listview and the id to match the des from the database.

Comment: Hi again . I tried http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92 but i dont know where can i fetch data from dataBase . please help me to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

When you start the new activity please be sure to send also the poem to your intent as.

```
String myPoem = ...
Intent mActivity = new Intent (this, PoemActivity.class)
mActivity.putExtra("poem", myPoem);
startActivity(mActivity);
```

Then in your poem activity in onCreate or onResum, you retrieve the poem string:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent()
String poem = intent.getStringExtra("poem");
```

All this in the listview item click.